# Set durationOfBreak in Polly CircuitBreaker

Tags: c#, polly

I am using Polly Circuit Breaker for an API which throws a user defined Exception if service is down for maintenance.
The Exception will contain a value how long the service will be down.

Is it possible to configure/update the circuit breaker policy after first user exception is handled ?

e.g.

```
CircuitBreakerPolicy breaker = Policy.Handle<UserException>()
.CircuitBreaker(
exceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking: 1, 
durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

Example()
{
    try
    {

        string response = await breaker.ExecuteAsync<String>(() =>
        {
            return client.GetStringAsync("/api/values/");
        });
    }
    catch (UserException ex)
    {
        var downtime = GetDowntime(ex);

        //how to update the duration of break ?
        breaker.durationOfBreak = downtime;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        …
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the `durationOfBreak` on an existing `CircuitBreakerPolicy` instance, after creation.

For *general* dynamic reconfiguration during running, the Polly team recommends [atomically updating a policy instance stored in the PolicyRegistry](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Dynamic-reconfiguration-during-running).

For the specific scenario:

> [the] API throws a user defined Exception if service is down for maintenance [which] will contain a value how long the service will be down

you could, more simply, use the circuit-breaker's [manual controls](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Circuit-Breaker#manual-control--polly-v40):

- `.Isolate()` to manually force the circuit open;
- `.Reset()` to manually reset the circuit.

You could `.Isolate()` the circuit when the given exception is thrown; and set a `Timer` to call `Reset()` on it at the time that the exception indicates the service should be available again.

Comment: I willl look into the option with PolicyRegistry. I was already thinking about the manual control, but this seems to me a pretty "dirty" way,

Comment: Note also that Polly provides overloads of the `WaitAndRetry(...)` policy designed to handle the case when the response includes information about how long to wait before retrying.  See https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#retryafter-when-the-response-specifies-how-long-to-wait . The circuit-breaker approach could be useful in the sense that the fact that the circuit is broken can be shared with other callers. The retry-policy can provide another approach so that each caller waits for whatever 429-type delay is specified to it. Not necess better/worse; just another option.